# Issue with writing XMLDocument

Tags: objective-c, xml

I have a non doc-based app with table view with two columns, whose Value bindings are bound to two properties of the arrangedObjects of an array controller. I have a NSMutableArray in my AppDelegate that hold the data, as well as the corresponding @property and @synthesize. I implement key-value-coding accessor methods and use those when inserting data to the array in order to generate KVO notifications. I fill up my array with some NSDictionary objects from xml file. I've got all that working (modify, remove and add items), but what I'd like to do is write it back to xml file.

```
xmlData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES
```

is writing to disk, but don't reflect changes when editing table view. There must be some tiny little thing I am forgetting. What is it?
Any suggestions would be very nice!

The code:

```
//  AppDelegate.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>{
    NSXMLDocument *xmlDoc;
    NSXMLElement *root;
    NSMutableArray *children;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSArray *children;

- (void)setChildren:(NSArray *)newChildren;
- (NSUInteger)countOfChildren;
- (id)objectInChildrenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)insertObject:(id)object inChildrenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)removeObjectFromChildrenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

- (IBAction)addObject:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)saveXMLToFile:(id)sender;
- (void) populateTable;
@end

//  AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

-(void) addObjectToChildren:(id)object{
    [self insertObject:object inChildrenAtIndex:[self countOfChildren]];
}
@synthesize children;

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{    
    [self populateTable];
}

#pragma mark - Indexed Accessors
- (void)setChildren:(NSArray *)newChildren{
    if (children!=newChildren) {
        children=[newChildren mutableCopy];
    }
}

-(NSUInteger)countOfChildren{
    return [self.children count];
}

-(id)objectInChildrenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    return [self.children objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (void)insertObject:(id)object inChildrenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    [children insertObject:object atIndex:index];
}

-(void)removeObjectFromChildrenAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    [children removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}

#pragma mark -
-(void)populateTable{
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSString *pathname = [@"~/myFile.xml" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathname];

    xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSXMLDocumentTidyXML error:&error];
    root = [xmlDoc rootElement];

    NSArray *array=[root nodesForXPath:@"number" error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *mArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSXMLElement *element in array) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[element stringValue],@"id",@"number", @"name", nil];
        [mArray addObject:dict];
    }
    [self setChildren:[NSArray arrayWithArray:mArray]];
}

#pragma mark - Actions
- (IBAction)addObject:(id)sender {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"id",@"number", @"name", nil];

    NSXMLElement *element=[[NSXMLElement alloc]initWithName:[dict objectForKey:@"name"] stringValue:[dict objectForKey:@"id"]];

    [root insertChild:element atIndex:[self countOfChildren]];

    [self addObjectToChildren:dict];
}

- (IBAction)saveXMLToFile:(id)sender { 
    NSString *fileName = [@"~/myFile.xml" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSData *xmlData = [xmlDoc XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodePrettyPrint];
    if (![xmlData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES]) {
        NSBeep();
        NSLog(@"Could not write document out...");
    }
}

@end
```

The xml file:

```
<root>
    <number>0</number>
    <number>1</number>
    <number>2</number>
    <number>3</number>
    <number>4</number>
    <number>5</number>
</root>
```

Comment: Let me understand what you are trying to do.  You just want to save your mutable array to a file?

Comment: @ El Tomato I want to save changes made in table view to xml file. Don't want to save the array in a plist (which is what writeToFile:atomically: does). I need to save changes to the same xmldocument.

Answer (score 0):

When you change values in the tableview the underlying array is updated but not your XML document. You need to update your XML document or recreate it from the array to hold edited values.

Comment: Is just what I'm looking for: how to update my xml document? Can you point me the right way to do this, please?

Comment: If all contents of your xml document is displayed in the table, just build the whole document again by adding NSXMLElements to a newly created NSXMLDocument and write that to disk replacing the old one.

Comment: Yes I can do it, but the xml document I posted is very simple (for example purpose), the real xml document is much more complicated (with nested nodes etc...) so build the whole document again is also more complicated. What I'm looking for is how to do it in the same way as in xmlbrowser, but I can not figure it out.